# 2x12 and 3/4" Play for stringer ledger?

Tags: framing, stairs

Scenario: attach 3 staircase stringers to floor i joists.

Problem: I joists have very few fastening points, about one nail per flange.

Would it be best to attach a 2x12 to the I joists (it will run perpendicular) so it would catch 3 I joists - and then nail or structural screw a piece of 3/4" plywood to the 2x12 for more strength.... Or .... Just attach 3/4" ply to I joists?

Also, using a 2x12 allows for the use of joist hangers, while plywood is too thin.

Answer (score 1):

You could attach 2x material between the cords of the I-joist that the stairs will attach to.

Attach a piece on both sides and bolt them together through the web of the I-joist.

Then attach your joist hangers for the stairs to the 2x material in the middle of the joist.

The other option is to add an LVL sistered to the I-joist on the stairway side. Giving you plenty of material to attach to.

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like you're proposing that the weight be hung on the I-joist web. I don't agree. Any substantial weight should be borne by the top rail of the joist.